# complex name - surrounding you with inferior (less talented) people

Tags: psychology

What is the name of the complex of surrounding oneself with inferior (less talented) people to avoid being eclipsed or overcome?

I have a vague memory that it was a Greek naming or one from classic literature, but I cannot conjure it up.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  To clarify a possible confusion here, can you expand your description of this kind of person by indicating whether they have a high or low self-esteem?  Are there other characteristics not mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

It's not greek, but... Wills classified this as a group behavior, and called it downward social comparison. The gist of the theory is that a person attempts to feel better about him-/herself by socializing and comparing with someone considered performing poorer in areas important to him/her.

Wills, T. A. (1981). Downward comparison principles in social psychology. Psychological Bulletin, 90(2), 245-271.

Answer (score 1):

Could the OP be refering to [hubris](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hubris)?

> Typically, overconfidence led the hero to attempt to overstep the
>   boundaries of human limitations and assume a godlike status, and the
>   gods inevitably humbled the offender with a sharp reminder of his or
>   her mortality.
>
> To the Greeks, hubris referred to extreme pride, especially pride and
>   ambition so great that they offend the gods and lead to one's
>   downfall. Hubris was a character flaw often seen in the heroes of
>   classical Greek tragedy, including Oedipus and Achilles. The familiar
>   old saying "Pride goeth before a fall" is basically talking about
>   hubris.

Related, see [Superiority Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superiority_complex),
and [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Comment: I may be wrong, but I am not sure this is the answer the OP is after.  To me, your suggested answer refers to someone who is overconfident and sees themselves as godlike, whereas I read the OP question to refer to someone with low self esteem and wanting to surround themselves with less talented people to make them appear more talented than they see themselves.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I suspect you may be correct, but narrowing it down - single word definition>Greek word>best interpretation of what the OP means (guess, eherm.).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism)

> Narcissism is the pursuit of gratification from vanity or egotistic
> admiration of one's idealised self image and attributes. The term
> originated from Greek mythology, where the young Narcissus fell in
> love with his own image reflected in a pool of water.

As to surrounding themselves with inferiors ... well at least in there own eyes they do.